# O que são covering, composite e compound em relação a indexes?

Tags: mysql, índices

Estou [lendo](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8213235/5429980) sobre indexes no MySQL e me surgiu três termos que eu não consigo entender muito bem que são: *covering*, *composite* e *compound*. Esses termos estão fortemente ligados ao uso de indexes, no entanto, não consigo compreender quais são seus significados e objetivos, e quais impactos eles tem na criação de indexes.

Portanto, eu gostaria de saber o que é covering, composite e compound e quais são suas diferenças em relação a cada um?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro entenda como se constrói um índice. Você cria uma árvore de busca binária (pesquise o conceito básico para saber o que é), que geralmente é uma árvore-B (que é um tipo mais complicado de entender então talvez não queira se dar ao trabalho, ela foi projetada para minimizar o custo de reequilibrar a árvore quando esta sofre muitas alterações, por isso é usada em bancos de dados e sistemas de arquivos, entre outros).

Você vai populando essa árvore de forma a ser possível buscar rapidamente informação relacionada aos elementos que foram populados nela, que é para isso que servem árvores de busca (por exemplo, você vai concatenando (ligando) nome e sobrenome de uma tabela pessoas e populando nessa árvore as concatenações, assim quando precisar achar informação relacionada a alguém com nome "Gato" e sobrenome "Silva" vai conseguir achar rápido (pela maneira como a busca é feita nessa estrutura de dados).

Note que a ordem é importante, você consegue achar rápido "GatoSilva"  mas não "SilvaGato". Como a ordem é respeitada ao percorrer os nós da árvore, pela maneira que a busca é feita se você tiver só o nome "Gato" ainda assim vai conseguir tirar proveito da árvore para restringir o espaço de busca (que vai se restringir a "GatoMendes", "GatoSilva", etc).

Pois bem, vamos aos termos.

Composite foi um uso errado quando queria dizer compound, só isso. O AR usa o termo mas aponta o erro depois. Compound é o passado do verbo compor, em inglês (alguma coisa ser composta por outras). Composite passa a mesma ideia de composição mas é substantivo (composto químico, design pattern Composite). Aí quem fez a pergunta se confundiu.

Compound index é índice composto, ou seja, o que não é o simples (uma coluna só). Isto é, o composto tem seus elementos gerados a partir de mais de uma coluna e é construído com base na concatenação dos valores dessas colunas numa certa ordem definida na declaração do índice e em seguida populando numa árvore de busca.

Portanto, de novo: um índice composto pelas colunas nome e sobrenome vai otimizar (ajudar a achar mais rápido) a busca por um registro que busca colunas nessa ordem, já se procurar por sobrenome e nome não vai ajudar, porque não é a ordem que foram populados os elementos ao construir a árvore de busca (uma analogia simples a essa limitação, só que invertendo a importância da ordem para sobrenome e nome, é uma lista telefônica (é do seu tempo? kkk) que está ordenada por sobrenomes, ou seja, "Silva Gato", "Silva Henrique", etc. Portanto nesse caso não vai dar certo você tentar usar ela para achar alguém pelo primeiro nome, e sim pelo sobrenome antes).

Por outro lado, voltando ao primeiro exemplo (e desinvertendo na sua cabeça rs, agora o importante primeiro é o nome), sendo o nome a primeira coluna, ainda é possível usar o índice composto para otimizar (agilizar) uma consulta contendo apenas o nome "Gato". Não sei se tem um termo para isso, acho que no explain do MySQL vai aparecer "using index" ("usando índice").

Por fim, pelo que entendi da resposta, um covering index (não conhecia o termo) é um índice que cobre (cover) todos os campos da consulta, e assim não precisa percorrer a tabela para achar as informações, somente o índice. Acho que o termo está sendo explicado errado na resposta, não seria um termo próprio que signifique "índice cobridor" e sim simplesmente "cobrindo o índice" (covering the index, algo nessa intenção).

Comment: Provavelmente esta relacionado com cobertura de índice o *covering index*.

Comment: Não achei o termo, achei alguma coisa sobre índice de cobertura em SQLServer.

Comment: Da uma olhada [aqui](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/glossary.html#glos_covering_index).

Comment: @gato Entendi meio vagamente. Parece que um índice pode ser chamado de covering se ele serve de fonte os campos solicitados pela query/consulta direto a partir dele e não buscando a página de dados apontada por ele, o que economiza I/O. Parece até se referir a dados de um índice que foram indicados por um outro índice. E recomenda projetar suas consultas para fazer uso dessa técnica de otimização. Meu conhecimento atual de banco de dados é insuficiente para tirar uma conclusão.